# Running the app as a service on Android

Tags: android, service

I have a voip app that has a serious performance issues when it runs on the background. Does running it as a service make any difference?

Making an app run as a service helps in avoiding shutdown by the Android OS? More information on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you run it as a foreground service then it will almost never be killed (unless there are really no other way for Android to free memory) and it will be treated as a running app, so there should be no performance issue.

You can get more details about [foreground services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground) in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

Comment: Absolutely right. Also, you can acquire a partial_wake_lock in your service if you want it to keep running while the phone sleeps.  Only do that if necessary.

Comment: In particular, for a VOIP app, you might only have it be a foreground service while the call is going on, as a foreground service also gets preferred CPU access IIRC.